# How to start a new Intent that will clear all other activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, back-stack

To lay it out as simply as possible. My user enters the app through Activity A. They "login" and then Activity B is started, and Activity A is finished using finish() so that the users can't get back to the login screen by pressing back from Activity B. Now in Activity B, they move to Activity C, and in activity C, I want them to start a new intent that will start activity A, but "kill"/"finish" all other activities. The only way I can think of doing this is using an Intent Flag. so far I've come up with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityA.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
startActivity(intent);
```

But the code above doesn't work. I still see that my app had a savedInstanceState in Activity B. Hence something like CLEAR_TASK won't work for me case.

EDIT: Also, is there an easy way to tell have many "tasks" your app has opened currently?

Note: There seems to be other flags that may help, but they were added in API 11, and I need to support API 10.

Flag combos I've tried:

**Doesn't work**

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
```

**Doesn't work**

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `IntentCompat`. like

```
import android.support.v4.content.IntentCompat;
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Comment: try finishing the current activity after startActivity(intent);

Comment: Hm. I didn't know there was an IntentCompat. Great! Last thing... do you know any way I can make sure my old task is cleared? I feel like this intent is clearing the NEW task?

Comment: I think it should work fine as mentioned in the document http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html .  And of course you can test your application. If you will find any problem we can discuss

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the below answer helps you:
http://www.hrupin.com/2011/10/how-to-finish-all-activities-in-your-android-application-through-simple-call

Comment: Thanks for the link. Although it seems like a "hacky" way to do it. I'll keep this in mind if no one else can help me find a solution. Thanks